# Why would objects under 85KB be allocated in the LOH (Large Object Heap)?

Tags: c#

I'm investigating the heap of a 32-bit application using WinDbg. The application is slowly growing in size until it throws `System.OutOfMemoryException`s. I know it has frequent LOH allocations, so I'm particularly interested in that portion of the heap.

Following this [tutorial](https://vimvq1987.com/exploring-large-object-heap-windbg/), I've run `!eeheap -gc` to find the starting location for the LOH, and then I've run `!dumpheap -stat <LOH-start-address>`.

I see in the tutorial that all of the objects in the LOH have a total size exceeding 85,000 bytes, which makes sense. However, my own LOH has many objects under this size. What could be causing this?

I've looked at some other tutorials to try to ensure I'm interpreting the results correctly. After reading this [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks/), I've tried running `!dumpheap –mt <methodtable>` to get the address of a small object in the LOH, followed by `!dumpobj <address>`. However, the object was still much smaller than 85,000 bytes.

For example, I ran these commands to look at one of the `StringBuilder` objects seen below. The backing `Char[]` was only 524 bytes.

Below is a snippet of the output for `!dumpheap -stat <LOH-start-address>`. I'm omitting many objects even smaller than the ones highest in the list.

```
...
6ce5ba24      383        48276 System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObjectTable+XmlSchemaObjectEntry[]
6ce6ac58       14        52392 System.Xml.NameTable+Entry[]
6ce62d80      623        54824 System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaAttribute
708023d0     2809        78652 System.Text.StringBuilder
70800958     1454        90336 System.Int32[]
70800460     2531        91024 System.Type[]
6ce5bc04      383        91300 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName, System.Xml],[System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaObject, System.Xml]][]
6ce67e30     5145       102900 System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName
6ce611c8     1451       139296 System.Xml.Schema.SchemaElementDecl
6ce63070     1105       167960 System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement
6ce6ac20    10202       204040 System.Xml.NameTable+Entry
70801ab8      183       366912 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
708032d0    94447      2266728 System.Collections.ArrayList
02fbe930    13110      2645968      Free
707fef34    96184      2910092 System.Object[]
6ce689d4   190453      3047248 System.Xml.XmlAttributeCollection
6ce69c38   329640      6592800 System.Xml.XmlAttribute
6ce68700   426488      8529760 System.Xml.XmlText
6ce67ed0   349123      9775444 System.Xml.XmlElement
7080316c     5287     44288168 System.Byte[]
707ff54c     2818     44655356 System.Char[]
707feb40   331949    102379016 System.String
```

Comment: Is this actually causing a problem?  I'm not sure asking why the compiler team choose to place and on the heap/stack without an actual problem has any benefit. I seems to be that this outcome is a side-effect and not a cause of the problem.  Most issues regarding out-of-memory are because the GC cannot collect objects it should because something is still holding a reference to it.

Comment: Limiting output to only LOH objects requires using two arguments so you don't get past the LOH end.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/06/30/sos-cheat-sheet-net-2-03-03-5/